# Cannot use import statement outside a module react native elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-elements

I am running into problems when trying to test a component with react-native-elements.
I am getting "Cannot use import statement outside a module" on import from react-native-elements.
[image]

My babel config is:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator'],
};
```

jest config:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/__tests__/testSetup.ts"
  ]
}
```

The test is:

```
import { Questionnaire } from './Questionnaire';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
describe('Questionnaire', () => {
  it('Should render', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Questionnaire setSessionState={jest.fn()} />);
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I did not have time to look into it unfortunately...